# regular expression to cut text

Tags: java, regex

I want to cut this text

```
UNIT=1111,SPACE=(TRK,0),DISP=(MOD,DELETE,DELETE),DSN=UUU.AAAAA.BBBBB
```

Result :

```
UNIT=1111
SPACE=(TRK,0)
DISP=(MOD,DELETE,DELETE)
DSN=UUU.AAAAA.BBBBB
```

I tried myself but I m so noob with regular expression, I used `(\S+)=(\S+)` to cut it but it not work correct.

Someone could help me ?

Here is my java code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\S+)=(\\S+)";
final String string = "UNIT=1111,SPACE=(TRK,0),DISP=(MOD,DELETE,DELETE),DSN=UUU.AAAAA.BBBBB"

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What tool/code are you using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use java

Comment: So show us the Java you've tried.

Comment: @slim I added it to my question

Comment: I'd use [`.split(",(?=[A-Z]+=)")`](https://ideone.com/L83okF), but there are no specs given, so, no idea if splitting is fine for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks

Comment: Or, if you prefer matching, see https://ideone.com/NUKN10

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As it works, it's good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead regex for splitting:

```
String[] arr = str.split(",(?![^()]*\\))");
```

This is assuming `(` and `)` are all balanced and unescaped.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM0fmN/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `,`: Match a literal comma
- `(?![^()]*\\))`: Negative lookahead to assert that comma is not inside a `(...)`

Comment: `(?![^()]*\\))` does not ensure the `,` is not inside `(...)`, it only ensures there is no `)` after 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` to the right of the current location.

Comment: As I wrote in answer if `(` and `)` are all balanced & unescaped this indirectly means comma is not inside `(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Working code ise here https://regex101.com/r/G355nS/2

```
^(UNIT=\d{4}),(SPACE=\S+\d+\)),(DISP=\S+\)),(DSN=[\S+.]*)$
```